# Did the Dilophosaurus understand Nedry?

Tags: jurassic-park

In *Jurassic Park*, after stealing the embryos and getting lost, Dennis Nedry has to tow his vehicle down a steep, but short hill. When he meets a Dilophosaurus (I am not going to point out the scientific inaccuracies with the design, since they are not relevant to the question), he says this when it doesn't move and just stares at him "No wonder you're extinct, I'm going to run you over when I get back down." After this, the Dilo spits in his face, and eats him in the car.

So, context aside, could the Dilo have understood what Nedry was saying, and just decided to make it so Nedry could not 'come back down'? All answers, please go by the movie, not the book.

Comment: No. The dinosaurs are merely dumb animals. Some slightly smarter than others, but none smarter than a dog.

Comment: do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: also, this is a movie, not based in reality.

Comment: The Dilo seemed to understand what he was saying. In Jurassic World, the dinosaurs are implied to be intelligent, at least in a way.

Comment: In the book it attacks him without him speaking to it.

Comment: the question is going off of the movie, not the book, I will edit it

Comment: On, my profile page, I saw that someone asked me if I have considered putting up a bounty for this question. The answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highly unlikely. We have no evidence from the movie or the book that any of the dinosaurs on Isla Nublar at that time were taught English. Even if they were intelligent enough to truly comprehend human language they would need to be taught how to understand it. I'm intelligent enough to know English but that doesn't mean I know Japanese.

At best they might (and that is a big might) be able to connect certain words to certain actions like a dog could know "eat" means food will be given. "No wonder you're extinct, I'm going to run you over when I get back down." Is far more complicated than simple correlation.

It seems much more likely the predatory animal was sizing up its prey and then did what it always does when something tasty comes near it. It spits in their face and then eats them.

Comment: Hammond was seen talking to a baby Velociraptor near the beginning. I thought that maybe all the dinosaurs could pick up a few words and phrases from him, since he was apparently 'present for the birth of every little creature on this island'

Comment: Talking to a baby for a moment isn't really indicative of teaching it.

Answer (score -1):

No in the book the animal was a juvenile. And paid no attention to attempts at taunting or tricks.

Comment: Neither of those mean it doesn't understand.  I agree it's not likely it understands, but neither of those make it impossible.  After all, a smart puppy can understand rather a lot, and it's juvenile.